# C++ How to read the specific element from a text file into a array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, stream

What I'm trying to do is, now I know the index of number "10", and I want to read it into the ary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int ary[1];
ifstream inData;
inData.open("num.txt");
for (int i=1;i<2;i++){
    inData >> ary[0];
}

num.txt: 0   10   20
three number and separate by a '\t'
```

But this doesn't work, what what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Its the 2nd number you're looking for so either change i to 0 or < to <=. Second, you need an array of size 2 `int ary[2]` or just use an `int ary` since you know the index and what ever was written in the previous iteration prior will just be overwritten by each subsequent iteration of the loop.

```
int main() {
    int ary;
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("num.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        inData >> ary;

    }
    printf("%d\n",ary);
    return 0;
}
```

with the array

```
int main() {
    int ary[2];
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("num.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        inData >> ary[i];
        printf("%d\n",ary[i]);  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works! The one without array is what I really want. However, num.txt has about 9 billion elements, and I have to do this searching action many times for different indexed element in num.txt. Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe use pointer to located the specific element?

Comment: you could use something such as fread() to read in chunks of it at a time into memory, something like an array, until you get to the appropriate chunk and then calculate the index in the given chunk by doing index%chunk_size which should work. Otherwise you would have to iterate over the entire file to your index. That also involves using a FILE pointer instead of an ifstream.

Answer (score 0):

your array of ints is of size 1.  i don't think it will work to iterate over the file.

Reserve more space to be able to read in the 3 values like,

```
int ary[3];
```

and also change your loop to:

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
```

i think that you should add this too:

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
inData.read(buffer,sizeof(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a specific element; no need for an array then.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int elementValue = 0;
    int indexOfElement = 2;
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("num.txt");
    if (!inData.good())
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    int currentElement = 1;
    while(currentElement <= indexOfElement && inData.good())
    {
        inData >> elementValue;
        ++currentElement;
    }
    if (inData.good())
        std::cout << "Found: " << elementValue << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "Failed to find enough elements" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```